# Recuperar dados struct em C

Tags: c

Como faço para salvar uma Struct em um arquivo em C e recuperar esses dados em outra execução do programa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue aqui um exemplo ilustrativo (testado) de como ler e gravar os dados de uma "struct" em um arquivo binário.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARQUIVO  "teste.dat"

typedef struct registro_s
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
} registro_t;


size_t gravar_registro( const char * arq, registro_t * rec )
{
    size_t nbytes = 0L;
    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "wb" );

    if(!fp)
        return 0;

    nbytes = fwrite( rec, sizeof(registro_t), 1, fp );

    fclose(fp);

    return nbytes;
}


size_t ler_registro( const char * arq, registro_t * rec )
{
    size_t nbytes = 0L;
    FILE * fp = fopen( arq, "rb" );

    if(!fp)
        return 0;

    nbytes = fread( rec, sizeof(registro_t), 1, fp );

    fclose(fp);

    return nbytes;
}


void exibir_registro( registro_t * rec )
{
    printf("a = %d\n", rec->a );
    printf("b = %d\n", rec->b );
    printf("c = %d\n", rec->c );
}


int main( int argc, char * argv[] )
{
    registro_t rec;

    if( argc <= 1)
        return 1;

    if( !strcmp(argv[1], "--ler") )
    {
        if( !ler_registro( ARQUIVO, &rec ) )
        {
            printf( "Erro lendo Arquivo: %s\n", ARQUIVO );
            return 1;
        }

        exibir_registro( &rec );
    }
    else if( !strcmp(argv[1], "--gravar") )
    {
        rec.a = atoi(argv[2]);
        rec.b = atoi(argv[3]);
        rec.c = atoi(argv[4]);

        gravar_registro( ARQUIVO, &rec );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Compilando:

```
$ gcc -Wall struct.c -o struct
```

Testando gravação:

```
$ ./struct --gravar 246 999 735
```

Testando leitura:

```
$ ./struct --ler
a = 246
b = 999
c = 735
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se os dados podem ser visiveis, pode-se utilizar um arquivo TXT para a alocação dos dados e acesso a eles mais tarde.

Aqui tem o básico para se utilizar a manipulação de text file: [Arquivos - PUCRS](http://www.inf.pucrs.br/~pinho/LaproI/Arquivos/Arquivos.htm)

Ou pode utilizar um banco de dados(mysql, oracle e etc) para melhor segurança dos arquivos e organização(caso so dados sejam maiores).

Utilize apenas o Text file se forem dados voláteis(como um acumulador, por exemplo) e com poucas informações.

Bom, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Podia fazer um resumo do que é explicado nesse link. Se um dia o link quebrar, pelo menos sua resposta não se torna inválida.

Comment: Note que, se a `struct` em questão tiver ponteiros, simplesmente gravar num arquivo não resolve o problema. Daí começa o campo de _serialização_ de objetos...